# Equivalent to Qt Designer's "Change objectName..." for C#/WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

In Qt Designer, I can rename a variable from Designer by right-clicking on it and choosing Context Menu->Change objectName...

[image]

I want to change the default names such as dataGridView1, dataGridView2, etc. that C# assigns to new controls, but I couldn't find an equivalent property in the Properties box:

[image]

I looked for "Object Name", "Name" or something similar. How do I change it?

Comment: Click on *Properties* button on toolbar of property grid. and change *(Name)* property. Currently you selected *Events* button.

Comment: Also you can use Document Outline window and select the control and right click and choose *Rename*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename a control from Properties window. To do so, select the control and press <kbd>F4</kbd> or right click and choose *Properties*. Then from toolbar of *Properties* window, select *Properties* button with wrench over paper icon. Then change *(Name)* property.

[image]

Also you can rename a control using Document Outline window. To to so, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> to open *Document Outline* window. From the control tree select the control which you want and then press <kbd>F2</kbd> or right click and choose *Rename*.

[image]